# Is it possible to have async generators where not all the values were consumed?

Tags: javascript

In the following toy example we have an async generator which is called for many times and never completed, since the calling function returns in the middle.

Can this cause a problem that would cause the function not to be called? Can this consume any memory?

```
async function* produceValues() {
  console.log("START");
  yield await Promise.resolve("a");
  yield await Promise.resolve("b");
  yield await Promise.resolve("c");
  console.log("DONE");
}

async function consumeValues() {
  for await (const value of produceValues()) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
    if (value === "b") {
      return;
    }
  }
}

async function main() {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    promises.push(consumeValues());
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);
}

main();
```

Comment: Not a problem. The generator will be garbage collected when the caller goes away.

Comment: The answers to both questions seem simple enough to test to find... The latter easiest of all; Modern browsers come with performance monitors that track memory usage, so take that code and run it, alone, in a simple page and look at how fast or slow your memory is consumed/collected. You will have to decide whether the average rate between the two is "good enough".

Comment: What do you mean by "*a problem that would cause the function not to be called*"? Which function is no longer getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that not all values are consumed, the generator still finishes so that it can do its cleanup. If you `return` (or `break`) during the `for await` loop, the `yield` will behave like a `return` statement; if an error occurs during the `for await` loop, the `yield` will behave like a `throw` statement.

```js
async function* produceValues() {
  console.log("START");
  try {
    yield await Promise.resolve("a");
    yield await Promise.resolve("b");
    yield await Promise.resolve("c");
  } finally {
    console.log("DONE");
  }
}

async function main() {
  for await (const value of produceValues()) {
    console.log("consume "+value);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
    if (value === "b") {
      return;
    }
  }
}

main();
```

As soon as the generator is no longer referenced by anything, it will get garbage-collected just fine.